# youtube api to get channel monetization status?

Tags: youtube-api

is there any API to check monetize status of Youtube channel? also for youtube video. i try youtube data api but not getting.or any other api to know that monetization is on or off.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this was asked a long time ago, but I still found the need of this nowadays. So after searching a lot inside YouTube API documentation I figure out that Google doesn't provide this, so I create a little workaround.

Basically what I do is generate an analytics report using the metric estimatedRevenue, If I gof 'Forbidden error' or 403 I tried again changing the metrics to not have estimatedRevenue. If this time a get the report data without errors that means that this channel doesn't have any revenue and therefore is not monetized.

I'm using nodejs to illustrate this because it's what I'm using in my project but you can adapt to any other language. You may want to look at the Google official client libraries:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries

The code snippet comes to this:

```
let isMonetized = true;
this.metrics = 'views,comments,likes,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,grossRevenue,estimatedRevenue'

while (true) {

    try {

        const youtubeAnalytics = googleapis.google.youtubeAnalytics({ version: 'v2', auth });

        const response = await youtubeAnalytics.reports
            .query({
                endDate: '2030-12-30',
                ids: 'channel==MINE',
                metrics: this.reportMetrics,
                startDate: '2000-01-01',
            });

        const responseData = response.data;

        const analyticsInfo = {

            channelId,
            channelName: youtubeTokens[channelId].channelName,
            views: responseData.rows[0][0],
            comments: responseData.rows[0][1],
            likes: responseData.rows[0][2],
            dislikes: responseData.rows[0][3],
            estimatedMinutesWatched: responseData.rows[0][4],
            grossRevenue: responseData.rows[0][5] !== undefined
                ? responseData.rows[0][5]
                : 'Not monetized',
            estimatedRevenue: responseData.rows[0][6] !== undefined
                ? responseData.rows[0][6]
                : 'Not monetized',

        };

        return analyticsInfo;

    } catch (error) {

        if (error.code === 403 && isMonetized) {

            console.log('Could not get reports. Trying again without revenue metrics');
            this.reportMetrics = 'views,comments,likes,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched';
            isMonetized = false;

        } else {

            console.log(error);

            return false;

        }

    }

}
```