# YouTube API: Check if Someone Else's Video is Monetized or Not

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There is a website called: [TubeSift](https://www.tubesift.com/)

This tool determines whether a video is "monetized" or not.

**My simple question is...**

Is there a way to determine if a specific YouTube video is monetized (can show in-stream ads) via some YouTube API?

**If yes**, which YouTube API?

**If no**, how then might TubeSift be determining this? Scraping the response?

**Important distinction**: this would be a video that you DON'T have authentication or credentials to manage - ie: it's someone else's video.

Similar questions asking slightly different things

- [youtube api to get channel monetization status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046636/youtube-api-to-get-channel-monetization-status)

**Disclaimer**
I realize this question seems off-topic because it doesn't have a code example but YouTube's [How to Get Help](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) says to basically ask questions here on StackOverflow for help.

> We support the YouTube Data API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers
>   monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api,
>   and youtube-v3-api tags.

There's really nowhere else to ask.

Comment: This question is very off topic.  1. SO cant tell you how TubeSift does anything please contact them.  2.  SO is not Google please search the google apis yourself.  3. Just because google says to come here does not mean that SO is google support and even if a google did respond which i have never seen on a Youtube API question the wouldn't tell you they were from google.    Do some research give it a try and come back with your code and we will try to help if we can.

Comment: TubeSift is not going to tell me how they do it so that's a not logical suggestion. Obviously StackOverflow is not Google but they do use StackOverflow heavily for support. No one said StackOverflow is Google support. That's completely false about the Google personel not telling you because most of them put it on their profile. Already did a ton of research so everything in your comment is really of zero value.

Comment: Did you get any answer

Comment: Sorry @RohitDhiman no I didn't. I did learn of some other tools (ex: [TubeTarget](http://gettubetarget.in)) but nothing clear. I think these tools are just scraping a response personally looking for an ad unit.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube provides API to YouTube content partners. I also checked the tubetarget and used **scraping** also but **scraping** is very slow as compared to the tubetarget

See [this](http://developers.google.com/youtube/partner) page to get enrolled.

According to youtube: When using delegation in the YouTube Data API, the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter is always required. The parameter's value is an ID that uniquely identifies the content owner. You can retrieve the ID programmatically by calling the YouTube Content ID API's `contentOwners.list` method.
[Detailed description here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/identify_content_owner)

[YouTube Partner Program overview, application checklist, & FAQs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72851?hl=en)

Also, check this

[YouTube Partner Program policies](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1311392)
Please let me know if you are able to get Content Id API

Comment: YouTube Content ID requires authorization from the content owner. When seeing if somebody else's video is monetized, I don't have such authorization. Have you actually been able to tell if someone else's video is monetized through the Content ID API? If so, an example would go a long way.

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping

Answer (score 0):

There is a free site that can check if a video is monetized with Youtube Data Api.

" How can I tell if a YouTube video is monetized?
With Youtube Data Api You can learn with some special inquiries, as we do. Or visit the video's page, look at the source code, and look for the string "yt_ad" to see if it has been monetized. The video is monetized if the string is present and set to true; otherwise, it is not. "

This site is "Youtube monetization check: [Youtube Monetization Checker](https://ytlarge.com/youtube/monetization-checker/) "
The owner of the site explained how it was found on the relevant site, but I asked the owner of the site to explain in detail for you, but he did not tell. My guess is it uses a different method with oembed json.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, i think if the video is greater than 10 minutes, therefore that video is being monetized, i read somewhere before that a video needs to have at least 10 minutes in order to be monetized, and obviously we can get the video duration via the API.

The json key is:

```
+"contentDetails": {#213 ▼
    +"duration": "PT4M21S"
```

The time is formatted as an ISO 8601 string. PT stands for Time Duration, 4M is 4 minutes, and 13S is 13 seconds.

But the way Tubesift does it is just an intelligent guess or maybe some randomizing the "monetized" tagged of a video.

Hope that helps.